# Internal web based code search tool?

Tags: git, search, startup, code-search-engine

I work in a small startup (4-5 developers) and all our code is versioned with git. I am looking for an internal tool which I can deploy to one of the internal servers which would serve a basic "code search" webpage and let you search/suggest by file names etc and also display the results by syntax highlighting and line numbering etc. Is there any free such tool?

Comment: may be [this](https://github.com/etsy/hound#quick-start-guide)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not free You can get a starter version of Fisheye for $10 USD.

I have had good results with Fisheye

http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/

Answer (score 0):

There is also gitweb. It doesn't have the fancy syntax highlighting but it's free.

Comment: Gitweb only let's you search for names of git repositories. No search for files neither for source code content.